# How to test properly React Dropzone onDrop method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-dropzone

I'm testing [React Dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone) and I need to check the onDrop function. This function has two parameters (acceptedFiles and rejectedFiles). I'm mocking the files like this:

```
let image = {
  name: 'cat.jpg',
  size: 1000,
  type: 'image/jpeg'
};
```

Then in my test, I do that:

```
it('should call handleOnDrop with more than 5 acceptedFiles', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(mockComponent());

    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
      images.push(image);
    }

    wrapper.find(Dropzone).simulate('drop', { dataTransfer: { files: images } });

    expect(setUserNotificationsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

This is my onDrop function:

```
const handleOnDrop = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
    if (rejectedFiles && rejectedFiles.length) {
      checkMaxFile(rejectedFiles, maxSize) && setUserNotifications('error_big_image');
    }

    acceptedFiles && acceptedFiles.length <= maxFiles ? onDrop(acceptedFiles) : setUserNotifications('more_than_5');
};
```

The expected result would be that handleOnDrop returns acceptedFiles but returns rejectedFiles and I don't know why.

Mime type it's ok and also size.

That's the function from react-dropzone:

```
  fileAccepted(file) {
      // Firefox versions prior to 53 return a bogus MIME type for every file drag, so dragovers with
      // that MIME type will always be accepted
      return file.type === 'application/x-moz-file' || accepts(file, this.props.accept);
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When passing

```
let image = {
  name: 'cat.jpg',
  size: 1000,
  type: 'image/jpeg'
};
```

Into

```
wrapper.find(Dropzone).simulate('drop', { dataTransfer: { files: images } });
```

It will think image is undefined or null.
The way I was able to fix this is

```
//Create a non-null file
const fileContents = "file contents";
const file = new Blob([fileContents], { type: "text/plain" });

 wrapper.find(Dropzone).simulate("drop", { dataTransfer: { files: [file] } });
```

This of course is how you would do it for a plain text file. For different types of images you will want to specify the image type instead of doing "text/plain"

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue while I was using the `useDropzone` hook. Using

```
wrapper.find(...).simulate('drop', ...);
```

did not work for me.

Instead, I simulated `change` on the `input` field. This fit my use case for unit testing the component. I don't care about testing the specific drop functionality of the component since that is out of the scope for unit testing my component. Assuming that `react-dropzone` functions as it should, I just need to test that my component handles the file drop event properly, which I can still test by interacting with the `input` field instead. And it has the nice side effect of being more generic, in case I swap out dropzone libraries in the future.

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {
  target: { files },
  preventDefault: () => {},
  persist: () => {},
});
```

And I define my `files` like this:

```
const createFile = (name, size, type) => ({
  name,
  path: name,
  size,
  type,
});

const files = [
  createFile('foo.png', 200, 'image/png'),
  createFile('bar.jpg', 200, 'image/jpeg'),
];
```

Again, it fit my use case to just create mocked up file objects like this, instead of using native `File`. You can add more properties (e.g. `lastModifiedDate`) if you need to, but I didn't.

If, for some reason, you feel you need to create proper `File` instances, you can do that as well:

```
const createFile = (name, size, type) => {
  // the first arg, [], is the file content
  // it's irrelevant, so I left it blank
  // you can fill it like ['foobar'] or [name] if you want to
  const file = new File([], name, { type });
  Reflect.defineProperty(file, 'size', {
    get() {
      return size;
    }
  });
  return file;
};
```

I had some issues going down this route in my testing due to the `path` property not being set. Checking the equality of native `File` objects is quite the hassle as well. The serialized file objects would end up being `{}`, which is obviously not useful. I'm sure you can make it work, but IMO, avoid the native `File` object if you can. There wasn't a benefit to using them in my tests.

Comment: was wondering how were u able to simulate your input onChange here? im facing the same issue

Comment: @suisied the first code snippet in my answer shows that

Comment: yea i know that, but whenever i add ie. mount( <Dropzone onDrop={mockValidate}>) and use .find to location the onDrop, and try to simulate it, it doesnt seem to get called when `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`

Comment: It's been a while since I've had access to the codebase for these tests, so I don't have anything in front of me that I can use to try and help you further. You may want to ask a new question on here and provide code snippets. Feel free to link me the question if you do create one. Larger code snippets might mean I can see an issue.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the react testing library and this is what worked for me properly ,
i had attached the test id to the div that took the getRootProps from the useDropZone hook,it does not necessarily have to be a div it can be any container element

```js
function dispatchEvt(node: any, type: any, data: any) {
  const event = new Event(type, { bubbles: true });
  Object.assign(event, data);
  fireEvent(node, event);
}
async function flushPromises(rerender: any, ui: any) {
  await act(() => wait(() => rerender(ui)));
}
  const onDropMock = jest.fn();

 it("The on Drop is called on dragging a file ", async () => {
    const file = new File([JSON.stringify({ ping: true })], "fileName.csv", { type: "text/csv" });
    const data = mockData([file]);
    const ui = <MyComponent onDrop={onDropMock} />;
    const { container, rerender } = render(ui);
    const input = screen.getByTestId("testId-for-div");

    dispatchEvt(input, "drop", data);
    await flushPromises(rerender, ui);

    expect(onDropMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I found all this info in the official docs [here](https://react-dropzone.js.org/)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is experiencing any further issues after creating stubbed files, I found also supplying a types field in the dataTransfer option to bypass some checks that react-dropzone uses . I'm using RTL so ymmv.

```
const fakeVideo = new File(['muhaahahah'], 'hello.mp4', { type: 'video/mp4' });

fireEvent.drop(getByTestId('test-input'), {
   dataTransfer: { files: [fakeVideo], types: ['Files'] }
});
```

Comment: This is not trigeering the onDrop function